# How to display user name from session in layout page in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

i am making mvc project and in layout page i am displaying user name from session variable. If session variable is null then it will display login link. see below code.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString() != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString() != "")
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <p><b>@Session["UserName"]</b></p>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
        </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Home", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Home", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

i set session in login action as below.

**Controller Action**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == login.UserName && x.Password == login.Password).FirstOrDefault();

        if(user != null)
        {
            Session["UserName"] = user.UserName;
            Session["UserId"] = user.UserName;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(login);
        }
    }
```

but i am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error see attached image.

[image: Error of Object reference]

Comment: Remove ''.ToString' for userid in the if condition.

Comment: Just use 'HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]'

Comment: yes.. its working.. thank you..

Comment: Cheers! I ll post this as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString() != null && 
     HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString() != "")
```

should be replaced with

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] != null &&
...
```

The problem in your code is that `.ToString()` can only be called on a non-null reference and your code doesn't prevent this at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

If `C# 6.0` (by default in `VS2015`) is available, null conditional operator can be used to obtain a more elegant code:

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]?.ToString() ?? "anonymous"
```

Also, I think that coalesce (??) can be skipped if empty string is required for non-authenticated users.

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]?.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove ".ToString()" in the if condition. Session variable is already a string. Just use, HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]

Since the session variable is null, when you try to do ToString, it throws the null exception.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString() != null && 
 HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString() != "")
```

with

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of possible decisions:

```
@if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"]))
{
using (Html.BeginForm("Logout", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { id="logoutForm", @class = "navbar-centre" }))
{
<table align="right">
<tr>
<td> Welcome : @Session["UserName"] !!</td>
                                                                                       </tr>
</table>
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
}
else
{
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Home", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Home", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Make these changes in your layout page.